# rails 4 "chained" has_one: :through relations work with persisted but not new objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, associations, has-one-through

I have a rather complex model setup:

```
class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base # STI parent class
end

class VendorLineItem < LineItem
  belongs_to: :unit_rate, class_name: 'Billing::UnitRate'
  has_one :contract_resource, through: :unit_rate
  has_one :resource, through: :contract_resource
end
```

Note that the above two classes are not namespaced, while the associated models below all live in a `Billing` namespace.

```
class Billing::UnitRate < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :contract_resource, class_name: 'Billing::ContractResource'
  has_one :contract, through: :contract_resource
  has_one :resource, through: :contract_resource
  has_many :vendor_line_items, dependent: :destroy
end

class Billing::ContractResource < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to :contract
  belongs_to :resource, class_name: 'Billing::Resource'  
  has_many :unit_rates, dependent: :destroy
end

class Billing::Resource < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contract_resources
  has_many :contracts, through: :contract_resources
  has_many :unit_rates, through: :contract_resources
end
```

My problem is with the `VendorLineItem` class, where I need to get at the associated `resource`.

If I am working with persisted data, all is well.  In a rails console:

```
2.2.3 :001 > x = VendorLineItem.last
  VendorLineItem Load (9.8ms)  SELECT  "line_items".* FROM "line_items" WHERE "line_items"."type" IN ('VendorLineItem')  ORDER BY "line_items"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
 => #<VendorLineItem id: 42, fire_id: 938774, type: "VendorLineItem", unit_rate_id: 716, units_utilized: #<BigDecimal:6184d30,'0.1E1',9(18)>, fire_department_id: nil, dollar_amount: nil, created_at: "2016-11-18 16:22:23", updated_at: "2016-11-18 16:22:23", total: #<BigDecimal:6184060,'0.25E2',9(18)>> 
2.2.3 :002 > x.resource
  Billing::Resource Load (8.9ms)  SELECT  "billing"."resources".* FROM "billing"."resources" INNER JOIN "contracts_resources" ON "billing"."resources"."id" = "contracts_resources"."resource_id" INNER JOIN "billing"."unit_rates" ON "contracts_resources"."id" = "billing"."unit_rates"."contract_resource_id" WHERE "billing"."unit_rates"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 716]]
 => #<Billing::Resource id: 39, name: nil, description: nil, code: nil, sort_order: nil, is_active: true, constant_name: "E0", created_at: "2015-10-14 15:59:00", updated_at: "2015-10-14 15:59:00", vendor_id: 1, resource_type_id: 37>
```

If, OTOH, I am working with a new instance, the `resource` comes back as nil (rails doesn't even try; no sql is emitted).

```
2.2.3 :003 > vli = VendorLineItem.new unit_rate_id: 711
 => #<VendorLineItem id: nil, fire_id: nil, type: "VendorLineItem", unit_rate_id: 711, units_utilized: nil, fire_department_id: nil, dollar_amount: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, total: nil> 
2.2.3 :004 > vli.resource
 => nil
```

But I can access the resource through an explicit chain of the associations:

```
2.2.3 :005 > vli.unit_rate.contract_resource.resource
  Billing::UnitRate Load (8.9ms)  SELECT  "billing"."unit_rates".* FROM "billing"."unit_rates" WHERE "billing"."unit_rates"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 711]]
  Billing::ContractResource Load (8.8ms)  SELECT  "contracts_resources".* FROM "contracts_resources" WHERE "contracts_resources"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 261]]
  Billing::Resource Load (8.7ms)  SELECT  "billing"."resources".* FROM "billing"."resources" WHERE "billing"."resources"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 34]]
=> #<Billing::Resource id: 34, name: nil, description: nil, code: nil, sort_order: nil, is_active: true, constant_name: "D5", created_at: "2015-10-14 15:59:00", updated_at: "2015-10-14 15:59:00", vendor_id: 1, resource_type_id: 19>
```

I can also find the resource through the `has_one :contract_resource, through: :unit_rate` association without a problem:

```
2.2.3 :007 >   vli.contract_resource.resource
  Billing::ContractResource Load (8.7ms)  SELECT  "contracts_resources".* FROM "contracts_resources" INNER JOIN "billing"."unit_rates" ON "contracts_resources"."id" = "billing"."unit_rates"."contract_resource_id" WHERE "billing"."unit_rates"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 711]]
  Billing::Resource Load (8.7ms)  SELECT  "billing"."resources".* FROM "billing"."resources" WHERE "billing"."resources"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 34]]
=> #<Billing::Resource id: 34, name: nil, description: nil, code: nil, sort_order: nil, is_active: true, constant_name: "D5", created_at: "2015-10-14 15:59:00", updated_at: "2015-10-14 15:59:00", vendor_id: 1, resource_type_id: 19>
```

Why is the `has_one: resource, through: :contract_resource` association not working here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is a long-standing bug in rails:

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/20827 [Closed]

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/33155 [Reopened here]